# How do I self-answer "What does this say?"

Tags: translation, transcription

We get a lot of ***translation requests*** at Chinese.SE, and while we'd like to help, there's sometimes very little about *the Chinese language* in the question, and a lot about the procedure for obtaining plaintext from a photo.

Once we have the plaintext, we can simply input the plaintext into e.g. [Google Translate](https://translate.google.cn/) or [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php) to get an approximate answer.

The aim of this post is to develop a ***self-help guide*** for use as a ***duplicate target***.  Instead of closing these questions as "off-topic" and linking to [an impractically long list of (mostly inapplicable) resources](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/resources-for-learning-mandarin-chinese), it'd be better to close as a duplicate of this self-help guide.

**Question**: How do I self-answer "What does this say?"

Answers:

- Input the text into [optical character recognition (OCR) software](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/36145/8099).
- What about [handwriting](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/36146/8099)?
- It's also possible to [input characters by drawing them by hand](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/36148/8099).
- We can also [search for a character by radical](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/36150/8099).
- Searching [modern characters by any of their constituent components](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/36182/18338).
- Searching [archaic character forms by any of their constituent components](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/36184/18338).
- What are some [commonly encountered Chinese characters?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/39175/8099)

Still don't know?  Ask on Chinese.SE but *please show prior effort*.  For example, I asked this question: [What does 我们已经帮您踩过了 mean in this peculiarly translated escalator sticker?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/36043/what-does-%e6%88%91%e4%bb%ac%e5%b7%b2%e7%bb%8f%e5%b8%ae%e6%82%a8%e8%b8%a9%e8%bf%87%e4%ba%86-mean-in-this-peculiarly-translated-escalator-sticker) and you can see what happened.

For things like seals, stamps, calligraphy, etc., it's sometimes impossible to get a translation without asking someone who can read Chinese (and sometimes even native Chinese speakers struggle with this).

There are Internet communities which welcome these questions: like Reddit's [/r/translator](https://www.reddit.com/r/translator/) (and [/r/ChineseLanguage](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/) has a pinned *翻译 Translation Thread!*).

Comment: Seals are possible to read with minimal training. I agree that calligraphy is not.

Comment: Really?  It'd be great to have an answer for that too (I don't think I could do it).

Comment: Sorry, that may have been an incomplete statement. I meant, seals are possible to read with minimal training for a *native speaker*, and only those familiar with Traditional Chinese (because Traditional Chinese and Seal Script share roughly the same character structure). About 60-70% of seal characters is about breaking characters down into components, applying a mental font change from seal shapes to 楷書 for each character component, then reconstructing the mental component change to the same structure as the seal.

Answer (score 6):

### Handwriting

**TL;DR**: Handwriting is much harder than printed text.  The first step is to improve the image quality.  Afterwards we can input the text into OCR software.

This is on a door where I'm staying.

[image]

If we put it directly into [Online OCR](https://www.onlineocr.net/), it says:

> No recognized text !

The image quality is too poor.

#### Step 1: Improve the image quality.

We can open up Paint (actually I use [Pinta](https://pinta-project.com/pintaproject/pinta/)) and go over the Chinese in black.

[image]

**Method 1**: change the brightness and contrast:

[image]

**Method 2**: select only the black text (e.g. [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) has Tools/Selection Tools/By Color Select):

[image]

#### Step 2: Input into OCR software.

OCR software struggles with handwriting, so we may need to try a few times.  If we input the second image above into [Online OCR](https://www.onlineocr.net/), we obtain:

> 请各位出入
>   头好蓝色水门

It made two mistakes:

- the original says [关好](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%85%B3%E5%A5%BD) (close) and not 头好 (meaningless);
- the original says [木门](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%9C%A8%E9%97%A8) (timber door) and not [水门](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%B0%B4%E9%97%A8) (water gate).

So it's not perfect.

However, inputting the third image into [EasyScreenOCR](http://online.easyscreenocr.com/) gives:

> 请各位出入
>   关好益包木门

It also made two errors:

- the original says [蓝色](http://youdao.com/w/%E8%93%9D%E8%89%B2) (blue) and not 益包 (meaningless).

#### Step 3: Compare the outputs; fix bugs.

We can compare these two transcriptions.  The writing is stuck on the inside of a blue wooden door, so...

- [关](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%85%B3) (to close) makes sense and not 头 (head);
- [蓝色](http://youdao.com/w/%E8%93%9D%E8%89%B2) (blue) makes sense;
- [木门](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%9C%A8%E9%97%A8) (timber door) makes sense.

So we can fix the bugs to obtain:

> 请各位出入
>   关好蓝色木门

(It may be useful here to [search by radical](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/36150/8099) to identify troublesome characters.)

#### Step 4: Translate.

Now we put this into [Google Translate](https://translate.google.cn/#view=home&op=translate&sl=zh-CN&tl=en&text=%E8%AF%B7%E5%90%84%E4%BD%8D%E5%87%BA%E5%85%A5%20%20%E5%85%B3%E5%A5%BD%E8%93%9D%E8%89%B2%E6%9C%A8%E9%97%A8) to give:

> Please come in and close the blue wooden door

Actually, it's not a very good translation ([出入](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%87%BA%E5%85%A5) means "come in and go out").  We can break this up a bit further using [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E8%AF%B7%E5%90%84%E4%BD%8D%E5%87%BA%E5%85%A5%EF%BC%8C%E5%85%B3%E5%A5%BD%E8%93%9D%E8%89%B2%E6%9C%A8%E9%97%A8):

[image]

Thus it realistically means something like:

> Please, when coming in or going out, close the blue wooden door.

Comment: What's TL;DR? Is it "too long didn't read"?

Comment: Yes.  It's basically an Internet way of saying "summary".

Comment: How does "too long didn't read" become "summary"? I don't see how it works.

Comment: I believe it started off as an insult to prohibitively long posts (to indicate "I don't have time to read that"), then people started commenting "TL;DR: [summary]" on other people's lengthy posts to save the future reader's time.  Then people started including a "[TL;DR](https://www.dictionary.com/e/acronyms/tldr/)" in their own posts.

Answer (score 5):

### Searching characters by their constituent components

**TL;DR**: We can find characters by inputting some or all of their constituent components.

[小學堂](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/ccdb) offers a component-searching interface, so that if you manage to recognise some components of a character but not the entire character, you can input those components to get a matching character which contains them.

Let's say that you come across the following character, and you don't recognise it:

[image]

#### Step 1. Identify as many parts of the character as possible.

Let's say that you've recognised 2「木」and a「彡」

[image]

#### Step 2. Input those components at http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/ccdb

[image]

#### Step 3. Click 確定送出 to get a list of matching characters.

[image]

> You should see the following if you did this step correctly:
>
> [image]

#### Step 4. After you've found the correct character, click the character (not the number underneath it) to bring up a pop-up box.

[image]

> You should see the following box pop up if you did this step correctly:
>
> [image]

#### Step 5. The box under 瀏覽器 contains a text character. You can select and copy the character, then look up the character under your favourite dictionary.

[image]

Comment: Great! It’d also be great to update the original question linking these answers. (I can’t do this easily right now.)

Comment: @Becky李蓓 oh, I see. I'll do it right now

Answer (score 4):

### [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition): Optical Character Recognition

**TL;DR**: Input a photo of the text into OCR software (e.g. [Online OCR](https://www.onlineocr.net/)), then input the output into some translation software.  This method requires a sufficiently high quality image for OCR to work.  (It doesn't work well for handwriting, or top-to-bottom writing.)

Consider using these websites for OCR:

- [Yandex](https://translate.yandex.com/ocr)
- [OCR.space](https://ocr.space/)

Let's begin with a real example: a funny photo I took in Tianjin:

[image]

So... *what does this say?*

#### Step 1: Use Chinese OCR to get the plaintext Chinese.

The best software for doing this changes over time.  I Googled `Chinese OCR` and stumbled upon [Online OCR](https://www.onlineocr.net/).  Another possibility is the Copyfish OCR browser extension ([Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copyfish-%F0%9F%90%9F-free-ocr-soft/eenjdnjldapjajjofmldgmkjaienebbj); [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/copyfish-ocr-software/)).  I understand both [Hanping Chinese](https://hanpingchinese.com/) and [Pleco](https://www.pleco.com/) are mobile options.

After uploading the image and selecting *Chinese Simplified*, we get:

> 这块位置we've alreadyetepped enthis area 我们已经帮您踩过了！

#### Step 2: Input the plaintext Chinese into translation software.

For example, [Google Translate](https://translate.google.cn/) gives:

> 这块位置
> This location

> 我们已经帮您踩过了！
> We've helped you step over!

For the words that seem imprecisely translated, we can look them up in a dictionary, e.g. [YouDao](http://youdao.com/) or [Dict.cn](http://dict.cn/), or even just copy/paste the whole thing into [Yabla](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php).

#### Step 3: Still don't know?  Ask on Chinese.SE showing what you've done.

Which is what I did for this image: [What does 我们已经帮您踩过了 mean in this peculiarly translated escalator sticker?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/36043/what-does-%e6%88%91%e4%bb%ac%e5%b7%b2%e7%bb%8f%e5%b8%ae%e6%82%a8%e8%b8%a9%e8%bf%87%e4%ba%86-mean-in-this-peculiarly-translated-escalator-sticker)

Answer (score 3):

### Drawing characters by hand

**TL;DR**: We can obtain plaintext by manually drawing characters one-by-one using various software.

#### Drawing on your phone

If your phone has Chinese input installed, you likely can already do this.  E.g., here I'm entering in my name into Pleco:

[image]

#### [MDBG Online Dictionary](https://www.mdbg.net/)

MDBG will accept hand drawn characters, but it does care about stroke order. Click on the "brush" icon next to the search box:

[image: mdbg.net stroke input]

#### Random websites

If you Google `draw characters chinese` there's lots of software in which you can draw characters by hand.  It'll change over time, and there's sometimes browser issues, etc.  So one random example is [qhanzi.com](https://www.qhanzi.com/):

[image]

#### Google Translate

It's possible to draw characters using [Google Translate](https://translate.google.cn/) by clicking the pencil icon:

> [image: hand-drawn 你 inputted into Google Translate]

Answer (score 2):

### Extended character searching by their constituent components: Small seal script, Chu silk and bamboo slip characters, bronze inscription characters, or oracle bone characters

TL;DR: Using approximately same sequence of steps as the [answer titled **Searching characters by their constituent components**](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/36182/18338), we can search for other varieties of characters, including **small seal forms** (小篆), **Chu silk and bamboo slip characters** (楚系簡帛文字), **bronze inscription forms** (金文), and **oracle bone forms** (甲骨文).

We'll use the same example in **small seal script**.

#### Step 1. Identify as many parts of the character as possible.

Let's say that you've recognised 2「木」and a「彡」.

[image]

#### Step 2. Go to http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/ccdb, and click the desired script form. In this example, we're going to look at *small seal script*, so we'll click 小篆.

[image]

> You should see an extended box pop up if you did this step correctly:
>
> [image]
>
> ---
>
> Note: The Chu silk and bamboo slip characters (楚系簡帛文字) option is hidden under *Warring States characters* (戰國文字).
>
> [image]

#### Step 3. Input the identified components.

[image]

#### Step 4. Click 確定送出 to get a list of matching characters.

[image]

> You should see the following if you did this step correctly.
>
> [image]

#### Step 5. After you've found the correct character, click the character (not the number underneath it) to bring up a pop-up box.

[image]

> You should see the following box pop up if you did this step correctly.
>
> [image]

#### Step 6. The box under 瀏覽器 in the row 楷書 contains a text character. You can select and copy the character, then look up the character under your favourite dictionary.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Search by radical

**TL;DR**: Chinese characters break down into [radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_%28Chinese_characters%29), so we can identify Chinese characters by searching via radicals.  This requires basic familiarity with Chinese radicals.

#### Step 1: Understanding radicals

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_%28Chinese_characters%29) and [Yellowbridge](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/radicals.php) list the Chinese radicals.  Chinese characters are written using these radicals.

Chinese characters are normally written ***top-left to bottom-right***.  We can search for a particular character by identifying its first radical.

#### Step 2: Searching via radicals

To actually do this, there‘s e.g. [Search by Radical](https://www.chinese-tools.com/tools/sinograms.html?r=) or [Radical/Strokes Lookup](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=radicals).  We take the character, e.g.

> ### 课

and identify its first radical.  In this case it is the left-most radical (*remember*: top-left to bottom-right):

> ### 讠

(It's listed as a variant of 149. 言.)

Then we find this radical, and click the link:

[image]

The following page lists most characters starting with that radical.

[image]

It's easier to locate if you have a rough idea of the number of strokes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Chinese.

- To help old people who can't use Pinyin, most native cellphone keyboard software includes OCR. Even you can use voice input. eg: srf.xunfei.cn pinyin.sogou.com
- Some Chinese meme such as you asked "我们已经帮您踩过了" mean，I recommend you use native search website Baidu.
- Make some Chinese friends to help you.

Answer (score 0):

### Commonly encountered Chinese characters

There are a small number of characters which are often used for decorations, etc.:

#### [福](http://youdao.com/w/eng/%E7%A6%8F/) (fú) = prosperity; good fortune

Often [hung upside down](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/2400/why-%E7%A6%8F-is-often-used-upside-down) as a decoration.

- [What do these two characters on cufflinks signify? (Characters identified: 福 and 壽/夀)](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/28634/what-do-these-two-characters-on-cufflinks-signify-characters-identified-%E7%A6%8F-and)
- [Does anyone know what this says and in what language?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/48923/does-anyone-know-what-this-says-and-in-what-language)

#### [寿 / 壽](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%AF%BF) (shòu) = longevity

This is written with [multiple variants](http://chardb.iis.sinica.edu.tw/meancompare/58FD/5900).

- [Does anyone know what is the characters means (丁財貴寿)?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/2511/does-anyone-know-what-is-the-characters-means-%e4%b8%81%e8%b2%a1%e8%b2%b4%e5%af%bf)
- [Is the meaning of this symbol "longevity"?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/3568/is-the-meaning-of-this-symbol-longevity)
- [What do these two characters on cufflinks signify? (Characters identified: 福 and 壽/夀)](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/28634/what-do-these-two-characters-on-cufflinks-signify-characters-identified-%E7%A6%8F-and)
- [What do these two single-character calligraphic artworks mean? (Characters identified: 忍, 壽)](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/36954/what-do-these-two-single-character-calligraphic-artworks-mean-characters-ident)

(Together 福禄寿 / 福祿壽 form the [Sanxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanxing_(deities)).)

#### [囍](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%9B%8D) (xǐ) = double happiness (made of two [喜](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%96%9C) (xǐ) = happiness)

A decoration typically seen at Chinese weddings.

- [Translate the characters in this sign](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/30286/translate-the-characters-in-this-sign/30287#30287)

#### [制 / 製](http://youdao.com/w/eng/%E5%88%B6) (zhì) = manufactured

This is often found as the last character (bottom-left) on stamps on teapots, etc.

- [Deciphering a seal on the bottom of a Buddha figure (Characters identified: 乾隆御製)](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1395/deciphering-a-seal-on-the-bottom-of-a-buddha-figure-characters-identified-%e4%b9%be%e9%9a%86%e5%be%a1%e8%a3%bd)
- [What does this mark mean? (Characters identified: 周桂珍制)](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/35716/what-does-this-mark-mean-characters-identified-%e5%91%a8%e6%a1%82%e7%8f%8d%e5%88%b6)
- [What’s the characters on this seal of the vase? (Characters identified: 景德鎮製)](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/35078/what-s-the-characters-on-this-seal-of-the-vase-characters-identified-%e6%99%af%e5%be%b7%e9%8e%ae%e8%a3%bd)
- [Round seal stamp on a teapot (Characters identified: 沈紅英制)](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/36555/round-seal-stamp-on-a-teapot-characters-identified-%e6%b2%88%e7%b4%85%e8%8b%b1%e5%88%b6)

---

See also the list of [frequently requested translations](https://www.reddit.com/r/translator/wiki/frequently-requested) at Reddit's [/r/translator](https://www.reddit.com/r/translator/).