# Translate Seal Characters to Mandarin? Picture #2 (Characters identified: 青鸞舞鏡)

Tags: seal

[image: Furniture Characters 2]

Here are more of the Seal Characters.  These are much more complex than the first ones I posted.  Any help is greatly appreciated in translating to classical/modern Chinese.  Thanks

Comment: I don't encourage asking a sequence of *what does this seal say?* questions; they're only barely on-topic for the site [this site is more about learning Chinese].  You'll likely quickly hit the automatic [*question ban*](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans).

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to this site and am just looking for a way to get these Seal characters translated.  I would appreciate a recommendation for another site if this one is not appropriate for this.

Comment: I honestly don't know.  The best I can suggest is the [list of resources](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/resources-for-learning-mandarin-chinese) but it contains a lot of irrelevant (and some broken) links.

Comment: Basically it would be preferable if you showed your research. Can you read Chinese?

Comment: Yes I read Chinese, though I am rusty, having studied it 40 years ago.  I can look up modern characters and usually figure it out, but the Seal Characters are beyond me.  I had a neighbor ask me to translate them, but they are past my pay grade.

Comment: @JwangChyunHou I suggest you have a go at the rest of your pictures using [this](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/36144/how-do-i-self-answer-what-does-this-say/36184#36184) as a guide.

Comment: Indeed, if people are upvoting these questions, then you won't hit the question ban.

Answer (score 3):

as droooze indicated, the characters are “青鸞舞鏡“ ( read from top right, bottom right, top left, bottom left).

the 國語辭典 has the entry: [青鸞](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000101996)

the third explanation is:

> 傳說青鸞喜歡對鏡起舞，故用以代稱鏡子。

so, i guess the seal is on frame of a mirror, is it?

Comment: I think I need to spend more time on these questions to demonstrate character evolution again ><

Comment: cui bono? for recognition or seal script, may i say, only a handful of users on this site can do it. for novices to chinese language, it’s like teaching quantum physics to kindergartener 

Comment: The Seal characters are on furniture, though I don't recall seeing a mirror.  They are on drawer faces and elsewhere.  As I said, this is primarily a favor for my neighbor.  I appreciate your help.  Seeing the connection between the old (Seal) and modern characters does have some learning value for me.