# Need help deciphering this seal

Tags: character-identification, seal

[image]

Basically, it's a seal on a teapot, I'm wondering if it's legit in any way. The characters should be something like 'name+surname crafter'

Comment: These are quite modern Chinese characters. We expect an attempt at deciphering writing in the question. Please try this guide [(How do I self-answer "What does this say?")](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/36144/how-do-i-self-answer-what-does-this-say) then edit the question with your attempt.

Comment: With the "registered" character clearly visible and that the characters are in Simplified Chinese. It could be very likely that this wouldn't contain any "name+surname crafter". I would think it only contained the company name.

Answer (score 1):

The top is 中国宜兴 the rest are unrecognizable.
The bottom is 徐汉棠制陶

Comment: Only one character is not visible. “中國宜興紫X工藝”, X is probably 砂.

Comment: @dROOOze I think there might be one more character after 藝, because of the layout. There does seem to be something. It could be the simplified 廠.

Comment: @DanielCheung you're right, I missed that...

Comment: Located in Wuxi City(无锡市), Jiangsu Province(江苏省), Yixing(宜兴) is the most famous producer of purple sand(紫砂) in China, especially the purple sand teapot. Xu Hantang(徐汉棠) is a famous master on purple sand art.