# Round seal stamp on a teapot (Characters identified: 沈紅英制)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

This is stamped on the bottom of a yixing teapot. Can anyone translate what the name is please? Thank you.

[image: yixing seal]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

沈 (right top)

紅 (right bottom)

英 (left top)

制 (left bottom)

Comment: Thank you so much