# Sign on the edge of a cross-country ski trail in Ontario, Canada

Tags: translation

This sign has been at the entrance to a ski trail.  I've been wondering what it might mean for the past couple years.  thanks for anyone able to translate.

[image: sign on tree]

Comment: The sign is in Chinese only. Why no English version of it? Can it be possible that only Chinese, and no other people bothering the land owner?

Comment: There is a sign in English stating that there is no walking on ski trails in the winter.  I don't think the "no picking plants" part is listed in English.

Answer (score 2):

These "what does this say?" are a bit borderline for this site (they're not really about learning Chinese), and why I started the post [How do I self-answer “What does this say?”](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/36144/how-do-i-self-answer-what-does-this-say).

Anyway, since I've read it already, and it's probably not that easy to use other methods...

> 这是私人领地。
> This is private property
>
> 请不要摘蘑菇，野韭菜或任何其他植物。否则你将会遭到检控，因为这是非法的。
> Please do not pick mushrooms, wild chives (?), or other plants, otherwise you will meet with prosecution, because this is illegal.
>
> 欢迎你在郊野小径散步，但地面上有雪的话，请不要入内（11月15日至4月15日禁止通行），谢谢。
> [You are] welcome to walk on the countryside alley, but if the ground has snow, please do not enter (from 15-th November to 15-th April going through is prohibited), thank you.

Comment: Minor correction, 野 should be interpreted as *wild* (undomesticated, uncultivated), e.g. *wild mushrooms*.

Comment: I made the corresponding edit.  I'm still not clear precisely what 野韭菜 is: I think that requires local knowledge.

Comment: @Becky李蓓 it isn’t an accurate translation of what the writer actually wanted to say; the writer probably isn’t a Native Chinese speaker and just directly translated the plant’s colloquial English name into Chinese

Comment: 韭菜, (Jiǔcài), in Cantonese (gau2 coi3), is a common vegetable known as garlic chives. It is a grass-like plant, usually chopped up and cooked in an omelette, which I hated to eat, (the chives I mean), when I was young because it looked and taste like grass, (while playing school sports I've got grass in my mouth, sometime) It is also found in certain type of meat dumplings, you know, the little flecks of green stuff in the minced meat? Since "mainland Chinese" like such greens, then perhaps it is not surprising that this particular green is singled out in the notice, out of other 植物.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I'd looked around for automated options before posting but for some reason didn't consider OCR.  I saw other translation requests on stackxchange so decided to go for it.