# Can someone please translate these characters for me? (Characters identified: 柔道)

Tags: translation, character-identification

[image]

Could someone please–p l e a s e–translate this text on this piece of jewelry for me. I've tried so many places and apps to figure it out but I can't get the answers.

Comment: I tried OCR in an attempt to [self-answer](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/36144/how-do-i-self-answer-what-does-this-say) this, but it didn't work because the characters are decorative.

Comment: Did the strokes break off or did they forget to add them?

Comment: I don't think they broke off.

Answer (score 1):

It is 柔道 [Judo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judo).

柔 means 'soft, gentle'

道 means 'way, method'

*some stokes are missing, may be omitted for style*