# Convert handwritten Chinese Characters into Chinese Fonts

Tags: traditional-characters, handwriting, calligraphy

I have a list of Chinese names in Chinese calligraphy. I'd like to enter them in a website with my mouse and have the app provide the names in a Chinese font that I can cut and paste in a Family Tree (Ancestry.com) or Word document.

Comment: Are you asking how to input Chinese by handwriting?

Comment: Google Translate has that. If you are on a phone, you may use Google Keyboard.

Comment: Some of the methods here will likely help: [How do I self-answer "What does this say?"](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/36144/8099)

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to convert what you write with mouse to words that you can type with keyboard. I think [yahoo website](https://tw.yahoo.com/) in Traditional Chinese can do it. Click the pen image and you can write with your mouse. The pen image is in right side of magnifier image. Magnifier image is in right side of search bar.

[image: After click the pen]

[image: Several images locations]

Answer (score 0):

If you have an iPad or iPhone, you can buy the remote mouse/keyboard App and handwriting input App for Chinese.

Enable Chinese font in your computer and you will be able to input Chinese from your iPad to your computer with your finger (better than using mouse)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an IOS device, the app Pleco is pretty good at OCR.  Or on a Mac, the app from Cisdem does reasonably well.  But you are likely to need to correct a few characters.