# What do these wooden sticks mean? (Characters identified: 天然香樟木 防虫，防蛀，防臭)

Tags: translation, character-identification

A Chinese merchant sent me a parcel with an ordered item and unrelated five similar wooden sticks with white ropes attached:

[image: photo]

I did not order those sticks and have no idea concerning the usage of these sticks.  Can anyone translate the text on those sticks?  What are these sticks good for? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Methods are explained here: [How do I self-answer “What does this say?”](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/36144/8099)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since OCR is probably not an option due to the cursive font, I'll give you some guidance. All strips show the same characters. It says:

> line 1: 天然香樟木 natural camphor
>
> line 2: 防虫，防蛀，防臭 anti-insect, anti-moth, deodorant

You now can also copy-paste the characters elsewhere to find out more.