# How can I recognize Chinese characters in pictures? (Characters identified: 興隆 and 禄)

Tags: translation, character-identification

How to translate a character from a picture into text? Tried different OCR tools but didn't get much success.  I want to convert:

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: I tried with LIOS, a very good OCR for Linux, but it doesn't like the hand-drawn characters. Great for printed stuff. The first one came out as 雪 and the second one it couldn't get. Employ a Chinese person to do that! Job creation!

Comment: the characters are “興隆” & “祿” respectively 

Comment: Ask for salary!

Comment: The general question is answered here: [How do I self-answer "What does this say?"](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/36144/8099).  It's not always possible.  I've been using [Yandex](https://translate.yandex.com/ocr) recently.

Comment: @Pedroski, come on, it’s a free mental exercise for an aged 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second image, because its background is white, it's easy to handle. Upload it to https://pearocr.com (*). The site will tell you that the character is 祿。

For the first image, which has a complex background, you'll need to remove the background. First crop the image to remove the outer "gray frame". Then upload the cropped image to https://bgsub.com/webapp/. This site will remove the background of the image. Save the converted image and upload it to https://pearocr.com (*). This site will tell you that the two characters are 興隆。

(*) On the upper left corner of https://pearocr.com, you'll see "识别语言: 简体中文". Click it and a popup window will appear with five options. The first option is simplified Chinese, the second traditional Chinese. Since you may not know to which your characters belong, you may want to try both.

Bookmark these two sites for future use.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Helped a lot. Regarding https://pearocr.com, you can find a translation icon in the upper right corner for other languages. You can choose English, then the interface will become easier))

Comment: @Михаил Демин Yes. Thanks for the tip. I didn't notice that icon because I could read Chinese. So, the first thing that caught my eyes was the icon on the upper-left corner. Your tips is great for people whose native language isn't Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer that may be easier is to simply handwrite these characters into software like Pleco. I find OCR or machine based interpretation of characters to be very hit or miss, so I prefer to handwrite them personally into character dictionaries. An example of how that can be done is seen below:

[image]