# How to type this character from 汉字大字典 in my computer?

Tags: characters

Today I was looking at 汉字大字典 and found this character in page 2000.

[image]

I wanted to type that character in my computer. I used [this page](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=radicals) to look up the character through its radical (in [radical     毛](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?cdqrad=82)), but that character wasn't listed

How to type this character in my computer? I would appreciate you could share how you found this specific character.

Comment: the unicode code point is u+23b91 http://www.guoxuedashi.net/zidian/z43036n.html

Comment: Would you please tell how did you know the unicode of that character ?

Comment: It's right on that page.

Comment: It depends on your IME. Not all IMEs allow you to input all Chinese characters. I don't think any IME would allow you to input *all* Chinese characters.

Comment: @fatpenguin That's my question. Without knowing what the ping ying of that character is, how do I know where to find it ? The OP "_look up the character through its radical (in radical 毛), but that character wasn't listed_".

Comment: See my comment above. If your IME doesn't have the character, there are several options. One is to add the character to the IME, if that's allowed. Another one is to try another IME. You can also try to look it up in an online dictory by sound or radical.

Comment: For example this website: http://www.homeinmists.com/hd/index.html

Comment: [How do I self-answer "What does this say?"](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/36144/how-do-i-self-answer-what-does-this-say) has several techniques you can try. Follow https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/36144/how-do-i-self-answer-what-does-this-say/36182#36182 carefully and you should be able to find the computer character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[zisea.com | 两分](http://zisea.com/zslf.htm)

> [image]

results:

> [image]

info page:

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is that,

(1) Open Google Keep (or other Apps).

(2) Take a photo of the page (or printed text).

(3) Extract the text. Many apps can extract text.

Unfortunately, Google Keep gives me everything on this page except this character 毛+昌 （on the hook).

Answer (score 0):

To enter this character in Linux:

Press ctrl + shift + u together (just hold ctrl + shift, then press u)

Release them.

Enter the unicode number 23b91

Press space.

jié

Comment: How does this help, when the OP didn't know how to get the character (or its Unicode) at all?

Comment: Well, if I were stuck, I would get the character by drawing, or use zdic.net like Mou used zisea above. Then, if I can't find the Unicode, I use Python ord('') which gives 146321. Express that as a hexadecimal  number and you have the Unicode for '' ! Amazing, the Internet + Python!

Comment: could not work on macbook virtual box Ubuntu Linux even with •fn + option + x•, thanks for your info.

Comment: Don't know about mac, never had one, but mac is basically unix.. 1. ctrl+shift+u 2. release 3. 000a3 4. space Steps 1 to 4 give: £